# document.querySelectorAll to find item based on multiiple condition?

Tags: domdocument, selectors-api

I am trying to find div based on combination of class name and data attribute. But it doesn't seems to returning any value.

```
var products = document.querySelector("div.productDisplay").querySelectorAll("[data-productId='" + id  + "']");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `.querySelector()` call will only return a single element. If that does not match the selector in the `querySelectorAll()` call then no elements will be retured.

Try using a single selector, such as:

```
var products = document.querySelector("div.productDisplay[data-productId='" + id  + "']");
```

Comment: Another question is that how should i find elements inside the products?  This doesn't support findByClass.

Comment: You will need to iterate over them and run something like [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) on each one individually.

Comment: Iterate? Should 'querySelector' return only a single object?

Comment: Sorry. `querySelector()` does return a single Element. It's the result of a `querySelectorAll()` call that you would have to iterate yourself (this returns a NodeList, so you cannot even use the various Array functions to help you). As such, `products.querySelector('selector').getElementsByClassName()` should work fine. If you are having more issues, try creating a small example on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and linking that here.